# Reference flow for OAuth2 password flow + 3rd party OpenID Connect

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid, openid-connect

We have a working REST API which uses OAuth2 password grant (for access through our own Web UI) and client credentials grant (for scripted access), and may allow other grants in the future.

Recently a request came up to support 3rd party Single Sign On through OpenId Connect (so we can support identity providers such as Google and LinkedIn, but also some of our client's internal SSO systems that support OpenId Connect.

I'm trying to understand how to integrate the OpenId Connect flow into our existing authentication, authorization and identity management architecture.

One important thing is our system still needs to control authorization and access token grants and expiry. We just want to allow 3rd party authentication and identity management as an option, from a selected (but flexible) list of providers. Basically the way I see it, OpenId Connect can, optionally, replace the password grant for some users.

Can anyone recommend a guide or a reference implementation for such setup? Am I trying to do something that doesn't make sense?

**EDIT**: By "existing architecture" I mean our own existing user database, which supports email / password based authentication (that using OAuth2 password grant). We want to maintain this DB / authentication flow but also allow 3rd party OpenId Connect based authentication.

Comment: Without explaining what your "existing authentication" is how would anyone be able to help? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jwilleke I added a note hopefully clarifying that